# JavaScript Link Ellipsis

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
function urlify(text) {
    var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
        return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
    })
    // or alternatively
    // return text.replace(urlRegex, '<a href="$1">$1</a>')
}
function dome() {
    var desc = document.getElementById('eow-description');
    desc.innerHTML = urlify(desc.innerHTML);
}
```

It replaces all urls with links, but some links are wayyy to long to display, this is what I would like it to do:

Before:

```
My version of a Five Guys Cheeseburger! Super easy to make at home with the same results as the original.<br>
Ballistic BBQ on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/BallisticBBQ
Weber Performer: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0098HR1I0/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=211189&creative=373489&creativeASIN=B0098HR1I0&link_code=as3&tag=babb0f-20&linkId=KNX2BA5WT32WIBWU
Craycort Grate: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004BRNUIC/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=211189&creative=373489&creativeASIN=B004BRNUIC&link_code=as3&tag=babb0f-20&linkId=JY5PJ6AMEZYANRUP
Craycort Hotplate: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0088NR4NC/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=211189&creative=373489&creativeASIN=B0088NR4NC&link_code=as3&tag=babb0f-20&linkId=FZJDNBTU7BYQMSJB
```

After:

```
My version of a Five Guys Cheeseburger! Super easy to make at home with the same results as the original.
Ballistic BBQ on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/BallisticBBQ
Weber Performer: http://www.amazon.com/gp/...
Craycort Grate: http://www.amazon.com/gp/...
Craycort Hotplate: http://www.amazon.com/...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the `urlify` function and add a `slice()`

```
function urlify(text, maxlength) {
    var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
        var u = url.length > maxlength ? url.slice(0, maxlength) + '&hellip;' : url;
        return '<a href="' + url + '">' + u + '</a>';
    });
}

function dome() {
    var desc = document.getElementById('eow-description');
    desc.innerHTML = urlify(desc.innerHTML, 25);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zhe9m5s6/)

Comment: @DavidThomas - sure, I know about it, but never use it, it's just always easier to type the three periods.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks, Guys!